# Html textarea is not clickable and unable to type text in it

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have the following textbox in my HTML

[image: textbox]

I have the following code:

```css
.contact-us-form textarea, .contact-us-form input[type="text"], .contact-us-form input[type="email"] {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px #BFB9B9 solid;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.contact-us-form textarea {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
```

For some reason i am unable to get the cursor inside the textarea and i am unable to type text inside it too. Why is this happening ? I don't have any JS attached to this textbox, i have debugged and tested this, also i have checked all the computed css properties and i don't seem to find what exactly is causing this problem.

Can anyone point me to what exactly i am doing wrong ?

**[My site link](http://codeandcode.co/demo/CarVault/html/V10/contact.html)**.

Comment: Snippet works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: The edit does''t show the bug !

Answer (score 6):

Please try this code. 
It's due to `line-height: 0;` style if you set `line-height:initial;` or you set any px to this property then it will work as normal.

Instead of:

```
.contact-us-form textarea, .contact-us-form input[type="text"], .contact-us-form input[type="email"] {
    line-height: 0;        
}
```

Should of:

```
.contact-us-form textarea, .contact-us-form input[type="text"], .contact-us-form input[type="email"] {
    line-height: initial;        
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I tested and found issue here.. On focus textarea getting line height: 0px.

See attached screenshot link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nSH.jpg)

Rest you know how to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit CSS, this would enable you to type in the message box.

```
.contact-us-form textarea {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing

```
line-height
```

Or try

```
line-height: initial;
```

from

```
.contact-us-form textarea, .contact-us-form input[type="text"], .contact-us-form input[type="email"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` for your input element and any other element in which it wrapped